# how to add new input field after click plus icon in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to add a new input everytime the plus icon is clicked but instead it always adds it to the end. I want it to be added next to the item that was clicked.

Here is the React code that I've used.

```js
const Input = props => (
  <div className="answer-choice">
    <input type="text" className="form-control" name={props.index} />
    <div className="answer-choice-action">
      <i onClick={props.addInput}>add</i>
      <i>Remove</i>
    </div>
  </div>
);

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      choices: [Input]
    };
  }
  addInput = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      choices: update(prevState.choices, { $splice: [[index, 0, Input]] })
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.choices.map((Element, index) => {
          return (
            <Element
              key={index}
              addInput={() => {
                this.addInput(index);
              }}
              index={index}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 'update' is not defined  no-undef. Update the code to include your update().

Comment: what does the update function do?

Comment: actually i just used 'import update from 'immutability-helper'' for updating splice concept in state.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit this get me stuck for a while but there was a problem with how react deals with `key` props. When you use an index as a key it doesn't work. But if you make **sure inputs will always be assigned the same key even when the list changes** it will work as expected:

```
const Input = props => (
  <div className="answer-choice">
    <input type="text" className="form-control" name={props.index} />
    <div className="answer-choice-action">
      <i onClick={props.addInput}>add </i>
      <i>Remove</i>
    </div>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      choices: [],
      nrOfElements: 0
    };
  }

  addInput = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const choicesCopy = [...prevState.choices];
      choicesCopy.splice(index, 0, `input_${prevState.nrOfElements}`);
      return {
        choices: choicesCopy,
        nrOfElements: prevState.nrOfElements + 1
      };
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addInput(0);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.choices.map((name, index) => {
          return (
            <Input
              key={name}
              addInput={() => {
                this.addInput(index);
              }}
              index={index}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Some reference [from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the
>   elements **a stable identity**...
>   ...**We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may 
>   change**. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
>   with component state.

Comment: I modified as per your suggestion but still same output .  I want it to be added next to the item that was clicked. can you give some other logic to fix it?

Comment: @NarayananS I think it works fine, maybe these components all look the same and you get the "impression" that it was added to the end, while elements have just moved.

Comment: Try to insert text to the last input and see if you click the first element "plus".

Comment: Yes i did . but its always adding new input in last